# Second Datepicker does not display Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, woocommerce

I have 2 datepicker in my checkout page: 1 for birth date and another for flight date.

[image]

The first one is okay but for the second one, the dropdown options for month and year are gone/disabled.

[image]

Here's the code for Date of Birth:

```
$fields['billing']['billing_datebirth'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Date of Birth', 'woocommerce'),
        'id'        => 'billing_datebirth',
        'placeholder'   => _x('MM/DD/YYYY', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-first'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'options'     =>   array('' => __('Select BirthDay', 'woocommerce' ))
);
```

For Flight Date:

```
$fields['order']['shipping_flight_date'] = array(
                                        'label'     => __('Flight Date', 'woocommerce'),
                                        'id'        => 'shipping_flight_date',
                                        'placeholder'   => _x('MM/DD/YYYY', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
                                        'autocomplete' => 'off',
                                        'required'  => false,
                                        'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
                                        'clear'     => true,
                                        'options'     =>   array('' => __('Select Flight Date', 'woocommerce' ))
                                );
```

And when I inspect the fields, there are no jQuery errors but here's the HTML code:

For Date of Birth:

```
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-first woocommerce-validated" id="billing_datebirth_field">
  <label for="billing_datebirth" class="">Date of Birth<abbr class="required" title="required"> * </abbr></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text  hasDatepicker" name="billing_datebirth" id="billing_datebirth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" autocomplete="off" value="">
</p>
```

For Flight Date:

```
<p class="form-row form-row form-row-last woocommerce-validated" id="shipping_flight_date_field">
  <label for="shipping_flight_date" class="">Flight Date<abbr class="required" title="required"> * </abbr></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text  hasDatepicker" name="shipping_flight_date" id="shipping_flight_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" autocomplete="off" value="">
</p>
```

What am I missing? Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Eli

UPDATE:

Here's the JS:

```
jQuery('#billing_datebirth').datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    defaultViewDate: { year: new Date().getFullYear()-20, month: 0, day:1 }

});
jQuery('#shipping_flight_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0",
    defaultViewDate: { year: new Date().getFullYear()-20, month: 0, day:1 }
});
```

Comment: please share your js code

Comment: posted @JijoCleetus